# Payment for an Invoice

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are sending a payment and Invoice to QuickBooks (desktop) via Ipp.

The payment is linked to the invoice. If the invoice fails (say some item on invoice missing in QB), the payment still goes through.

Can we make the payment posting to QuickBooks fail if the parent Invoice posting failed?

Comment: Are you telling the payment to apply to the invoice?

Comment: yes we are setting <Line><Amount>202</Amount><TxnId idDomain="QB">10554</TxnId><TxnNum>2004</TxnNum></Line>

Comment: I would report it to Intuit as a bug then, together with XML which they can use to reproduce it. The payment should fail if the invoice you're applying it to doesn't exist.